# SDL Web 8 - Issue with publishing

Tags: web8, publishing, topology-manager

I have recently upgraded my CM database from Tridion 2013 SP1 to SDL Web 8 and setup the TTM and Business process type as per the [doc](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-75FE1F4F-B38F-4678-B1E1-83D07C1067EE&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-75FE1F4F-B38F-4678-B1E1-83D07C1067EE.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-75FE1F4F-B38F-4678-B1E1-83D07C1067EE).

I have created the Business Process Type and mapped it to my Publication in CM and when I triggered publish, items are being sent to Publishing Queue, but I don't see them appearing in the publish queue/queue_consumers table. In the event log I observed the following error:

> No Publish Transactions created for (un-)publish action for Publication 'tcm:0-12-1'. Reason: no mappings have been found.

I have verified my "Business Process Type - Topology-Topology type- CD Environment - Website - Wep application" mapping, they seems to be fine. Is the above error complaining about the mapping issue with TTM? Or any other mapping which was introduced in Web 8? Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Thanks Peter & Mukesh for your inputs! Issue got resolved after adding TTM mapping.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like you haven't added a mapping for that Publication to an environment.

You do that using `Add-TtmMapping`. For more information, see the following documentation page: [Mapping a Publication to a Web Application](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-92B9DFBA-E3F6-43F1-8B36-D8B064218399)

Answer (score 7):

As Peter has already mentioned, you are missing steps required to map a publication to a web application. I could understand the confusion is because this step is not mentioned clearly in points mentioned in the document you are following [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-75FE1F4F-B38F-4678-B1E1-83D07C1067EE&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-75FE1F4F-B38F-4678-B1E1-83D07C1067EE.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-75FE1F4F-B38F-4678-B1E1-83D07C1067EE).

Although it is indicated briefly in the point [Configuring your delivery infrastructure in Topology Manager](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-52727C62-2976-476F-8F83-6A980DC585E7&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-52727C62-2976-476F-8F83-6A980DC585E7.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-52727C62-2976-476F-8F83-6A980DC585E7), but that doesn't clarifying why this step is not mentioned in the steps required to setup publishing. The primary reason which I could understand to mention this point separately is because if you create a site through site wizard available in "Sites" menu available in CME, running of `Add-TtmMapping` script is not required. If you have setup the site manually and not through site-wizard, you are required to map it with your web publication by running `Add-TtmMapping` script.